# Is there a Tychonoff space with $G_\delta$ diagonal that isn't submetrizable?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Recently, I'm interested in the topological spaces with $G_\delta$ diagonal. Could someone give me some examples such that the given topology space is a Tychonoff space with a $G_\delta$ diagonal but not submetrizable?  The more, the better.

Submetrizable = if we can choose a coarser topology on the space $X$ and thus make it a metrizable space.

**One more question:** How could I know the topological space is not submetrizable? Such as $X$ is not $T_2$ or has not $G_\delta$ diagonal, or has not regular $G_\delta$ diagonal, or has not zeroset diagonal. Is there some other tools that I could use to judge that the space is not submetrizable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [A Space with G-delta Diagonal that is not Submetrizable](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/08/10/a-space-with-g-delta-diagonal-that-is-not-submetrizable/) at Dan Ma's Topology Blog.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You probably want to look at Aleksander V. Arhangel’skii & Raushan Z. Buzyakova, *The rank of the diagonal and submetrizability*, Commentationes Mathematicae Universitatis Carolinae, Vol. 47 (2006), No. 4, 585-597, which is available [here](http://dml.cz/dmlcz/119619) in PDF. Example 2.9 is a separable Tikhonov Moore space that is not submetrizable but has a $G_\delta$-diagonal. (In fact it has a rank $3$ diagonal.) Example 2.17, due to Mike Reed, is a non-separable Tikhonov Moore space that is not submetrizable but has a $G_\delta$-diagonal.

Another example is the [Mrówka space $\Psi$](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/tag/mrowka-space/), which is Tikhonov, separable, pseudocompact, not countably compact, and not submetrizable but does have a $G_\delta$-diagonal (even a rank $2$ diagonal).

Comment: Thanks! One more question: How could I know the topological space is not submetrizable? Such as $X$ is not $T_2$ or has not $G_\delta$ diagonal, or has not regular $G_\delta$ diagonal, or has not zeroset diagonal. Is there some other tools that I could use to judge that the space is not submetrizable?

Comment: corollary 2.3 of that paper has a necessary and sufficient condition for star-Lindelöf spaces (weakly normal and rank for the diagonal 5), which thus also applies to separable spaces. $\Psi$ is not submetrizable because a submetrizable pseudocompact space is metrizable (also in the paper).

Comment: @John: I can’t add much to what Henno has already mentioned. One other line of attack is via *Dieudonné completeness*, since every submetrizable Tikhonov is Dieudonné complete; the concept is defined and numerous basic results about it are given in Exercise 8.5.13 of Engelking’s *General Topology*.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott,the answer and the remarks feed me a lot. Thanks!